# Jquery skipping over elements in selector when element that doesn't match selector is added to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write an autocomplete widget. The requirements call for a horizontal rule element dividing portions of the list. This hr and in particular any li will break the proper highlighting of the selected item.

https://jsbin.com/rofohe/edit?html,console,output

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  Autocomplete sandbox for selection highlighting: simple elements; adding a li element that doesn't match the selector will break the navigation.
  <br>
Type Here:<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<ul role="presentation">
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button >A</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button >B</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button >C</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button>D</button>
    </li>

<!--    <li>    <hr class="fab-rule--black"> </li>  <li> nothing </li>-->


    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button >A1</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
            <button >B1</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button>C1</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
            <button >D1</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <button >E1</button>
    </li>
</ul>
    <div id="log">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:
    .selected { background-color : red; }

JS:

```
    $("#textbox1").keyup(function(){

            var     $autocompleteElements = $("ul li[role='presentation']"),
                    $autocompleteSelected = $("ul li.selected"),
                    autocompleteSelectedIndex = $autocompleteSelected.index();
console.log("autocompleteselectedindex:"+autocompleteSelectedIndex);
                    $autocompleteSelected.removeClass('selected');
                    switch (event.keyCode) {
                        //They pressed the up arrow 
                        case 38:
                            //add the selected class on the prev array item
                            if (autocompleteSelectedIndex == -1) {autocompleteSelectedIndex =0;}
                            $autocompleteElements.eq(autocompleteSelectedIndex - 1).addClass("selected");
                            break;
                        //They pressed the down arrow
                        case 40:
                            if (autocompleteSelectedIndex == $autocompleteElements.length) { autocompleteSelectedIndex = $autocompleteElements.length -1; }
                            //add the selected class on the next array item
                            $autocompleteElements.eq(autocompleteSelectedIndex + 1).addClass("selected");
                            break;
                        //They pressed the Esc key
                        case 27:
                            $firstAutocompleteSelectedChild = $($($autocompleteSelected[0]).children()[0]);
                            //if the selected item is a link, execute the link
                            if ( $firstAutocompleteSelectedChild.is("a") ) {
                                window.location = $firstAutocompleteSelectedChild.attr("href");
                            } else { //assumes we are a button
                                //if the selected item was a normal selection, put the search query in the search input ..
                                $target.closest("[data-search-form]").find("[data-search-input]").val(
                                    $firstAutocompleteSelectedChild.attr("data-search-input")
                                );
                                //..and close the autocomplete panel
                                closePanel(target);
                            }
                            break;
                    }

    });
```

Place your cursor in the input box and arrow up / down.  You should be able to cycle through the elements without issue.  Now pull one of the li elements that are commented out and insert it below the commented out snippet. The arrow navigation no longer works.  The arrowing breaks after you arrow past the li element that was just added. Arrowing up is also broken when you go past the problematic li element.

I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Does the jsbin not work?

Comment: It might work, but you need to post your code in your question first. Sites like jsbin, jsfiddle, et al can supplement the code in your question and should never be the sole source of it. What will happen if jsbin is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that indexes in jQuery have a scoping component to to them.  Changing

```
autocompleteSelectedIndex = $autocompleteSelected.index();
```

to

```
autocompleteSelectedIndex = $autocompleteElements.index($autocompleteSelected);
```

fixes the issue.